# Special symbols pattern search with str_detect

Tags: r, regex, text, dplyr, stringr

Suppose I have the following df:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

input <- data.frame(
Id = c(1:6),
text = c("(714.4) (714) (714*)", "(714.33)", "(189) (1938.23)", "(714.93+) (714*)", "(719)", "(718.4)"))
```

And I would like to obtain the following output:

```
Output <- data.frame(
Id = c(1:6),
text = c("(714.4) (714) (714*)", "(714.33)", "(189) (1938.23)",
 "(714.93+) (714*)", "(719) (299)", "(718.4)"),
first_match = c(1,0,0,0,1,0),
second_match = c(1,1,0,1,1,0))
```

This is, for the first column I want a one if (714)|(719)|(718) appear.
For the second column I want a one if (714.33)|(714*)|(719) appear

In cases in which I want to evaluate if a pattern is in a string I use *str_detect* function from *stringr* package. However, in this case, with symbols such as [. + *] I am not obtaining the expected output.

I have tried the following code, which obviously failed:

```
attempt_1 <- input %>%
  mutate(first_match = ifelse(str_detect(text, "(714)|(719)|(718)"), 1, 0), 
         second_match = ifelse(str_detect(text, "(714\\.33)|(714\\*)|(719)"), 1, 0))

attempt_2 <- input %>%
 mutate(first_match = ifelse(str_detect(text, fixed("(714)|(719)")), 1, 0), 
        second_match = ifelse(str_detect(text, "(714\\.33)|(714\\*)"), 1, 0))
```

I tried to escape special symbols and also tried with exact match with the fixed parameter (I suppose it fails cause the | is not interpreted as an OR)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can escape the `(`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
input %>%
    mutate(first_match = +(str_detect(text, "\\(714\\)|\\(719\\)")),
        second_match = +(str_detect(text, "\\(714\\.33\\)|\\(714\\*\\)|\\(719\\)")))
#   Id                 text first_match second_match
#1  1 (714.4) (714) (714*)           1            1
#2  2             (714.33)           0            1
#3  3      (189) (1938.23)           0            0
#4  4     (714.93+) (714*)           0            1
#5  5                (719)           1            1
#6  6              (718.4)           0            0
```

Comparing with OP's expected output

```
Output
#  Id                 text first_match second_match
#1  1 (714.4) (714) (714*)           1            1
#2  2             (714.33)           0            1
#3  3      (189) (1938.23)           0            0
#4  4     (714.93+) (714*)           0            1
#5  5          (719) (299)           1            1
#6  6              (718.4)           0            0
```

---

In the OP's code, the first one didn't work because the `(` is a metacharacter, and in the second attempt, the `|` is considered as fixed

Comment: You are right man. I was blind and did not realize that the parentheses was also a special character. However, I have a question, why did you add a "+" symbol at the beginning of the str_detect function?

Comment: @torakxkz Just a hack to coerce the logical to binary.  You could also use `as.integer`.  But `ifelse` for doing that is a bit of stretch because the TRUE/FALSE represents 1/0